# Change background colour on button click toggleable

Tags: javascript, button, background

I'm trying to make a toggleable button with the label class "Toggle" change the background of the website on click.

My html is:

```
<label class="Toggle" id="Toggle-bg" onclick="Togglebg()>
<input type="Checkbox">
<span class="Slider Rounded"></span>
</label>
<p id="Toggle-p">Toggle background</p>
```

and I would like to add this CSS to the document when it is clicked:

```
.Background{background: linear-gradient(45deg,lightblue,lightgreen,yellow,orange)}
```

I'd like it to be toggleable but load the page untoggled, thanks!

Javascript or jquery is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean variable for the toggle mechanism.

```js
let togg = false;

document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("click", Togglebg);

function Togglebg() {
  if (togg) {
    console.log(togg);
    document.getElementById("Toggle-p").style.background = "white";
    togg = false;
  } else {
      console.log(togg);

    togg = true;
    document.getElementById("Toggle-p").style.background = "linear-gradient(45deg, lightblue, lightgreen, yellow, orange";
  }
}
```

```css
.Background {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, lightblue, lightgreen, yellow, orange)
}
```

```html
<label class="Toggle" id="Toggle-bg"> <input id="inp" type="Checkbox">
<span class="Slider Rounded"></span>
</label>
<p id="Toggle-p">Toggle background</p>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it properly, is it possible to make the label the toggle button?

Answer (score 0):

you only need to use `classList.toggle` at your element target. you can create your function passing a `target` element to be reusable:

```
function Togglebg(target) {
  target.classList.toggle('Background')
}
```

and remove `onclick="Togglebg()` from your `label` element. Attach the label's click `eventListener` at your javascript file.

below a snippet implementation:

```js
function Togglebg(target) {
  target.classList.toggle('Background')
}

const toggler = document.querySelector('#Toggle-bg')

toggler.addEventListener('click', () => Togglebg(document.querySelector('body')))
```

```css
.Background{background: linear-gradient(45deg,lightblue,lightgreen,yellow,orange)}
```

```html
<label class="Toggle" id="Toggle-bg">
<input type="Checkbox">
<span class="Slider Rounded"></span>
</label>
<p id="Toggle-p">Toggle background</p>
```